# Add Meteor to exist node app

Tags: node.js, meteor

I have a node app that uses mongodb and mostly angular1 on the client. 
The node app expose REST API, WebSocket, TCP socket and handle business logic and login logic.

I'll like to understand what it takes to either add Meteor to this all or migrate the app to Meteor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go to meteor.com and do a tutorial. It will help you to understand the differences better.

It is rather wide question, but by your description it feels that direct migration would be rather painful, but I might be wrong. Certainly rest api, websockets, tcp sockets and login logic would need to be rewritten. And most likely business logic as well, to use Meteor reactivity. Without that, it would be no gain from such migration.

Comment: I have done Meteor tutorial and build some small apps with it, I hope for a way and understand the difference. My app is not good fit with meteor as while, there are some parts that will benefit most from the reactivity and for that I'm looking on ddp server.